# Why is my Excel macro downloading broken files?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file that has some links to pdf documents stored in Sharepoint Online. The file name of the pdf is in column A and the URL to the pdf is in column B. My macro goes through each row and attempts to download each pdf. But for some reason, all the pdfs that get downloaded are 3.88 kb in size and none of them open successfully. Why is that?

```
Option Explicit

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
      Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr _
      ) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "Wininet.dll" _
      Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" (ByVal lpszUrlName As String) As Long


Public Const ERROR_SUCCESS As Long = 0
Public Const BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION As Long = &H10
Public Const INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD As Long = &H80000000

Sub DownloadFilesInExcel() 
    Dim i As Long, ret As Long, sWAN As String, sLAN As String
    
        For i = 2 To Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            sLAN = "C:\Users\Prebek\Documents\MacroDownloads\" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value 'put desired file name in column A
            sWAN = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value 'put link URL in column B
            ret = URLDownloadToFile(0&, sWAN, sLAN, BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION, 0&)
            If ret = 0 Then Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4) = "File successfully downloaded" 'download confirmation message in column 4
        Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255264/sharepoint-api-and-vba-access-denied

Comment: I test your code work fine here, check the files is not corrupted, download it manually and check that it is not the file itself that has this size and error.

Comment: 3.88 kb looks about the right size for an HTML page telling you something about the problems you're having with these downloads.  Change the extension for one of the files to .html and open it in a browser.